# Blown head gasket on a 2003 Honda civic

Tags: honda, civic, head-gasket

I had a master ASE tech tell me that my head gasket is blown. Possibly a pinhole leak, of course they won't know the extent till it's taken apart. My question is how much will a job like this cost for this car?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably edit your question if you want to avoid votes to close due to shopping advice being at risk of becoming out of date.  If you change cost to refer to labor hours required (or equivalent), that isn't something that's likely to become immediately closed.