# Labor cost/cost of head gasket repair/replacement on 2003 Honda civic

Tags: honda, civic, head-gasket

I had a ASE master tech tell me I have a blown head gasket. How many hours of labor will this cost, and what will the gasket/resurfacing et cetera cost?

Thank you

Comment: Pay heed to what the moderator said in your [last question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/15290/675), which this question duplicates. Asking the same question multiple times won't get you an answer if the question is not a good fit for the SE site. Voting to put this question on hold.

Comment: Why didn't you ask the technician what it will cost?